# Calling component in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react and i come to this new syntax please help me to understand it better.

```
class Car extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {color: "red"};
  }

 render() {
    return <h2>I am a {this.state.color} Car!</h2>;
  }
}

root.render(<Car color="red"/>);
```

I have created a class component and as in object oriented programing we should create the instance of class to use it but here we are not initiating a class instance we just write the name of class in jsx language.

can anyone help me here what's happening behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Actually react take cares of it on its own. We dont need to create instance while using recactjs.

please read the explanation here in offcial doc of reactjs.
(There mentioned below sentence.)

> "Function components don’t have instances at all. Class components
> have instances, but you never need to create a component instance
> directly—React takes care of this."

https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html

Answer (score 0):

React is a library and does it so you don't have to worry about it.

The syntax you just saw is JSX. It is just syntactic sugar for [`React.CreateElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html). And when you go to the [React source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js) you can see that a constructor is actually called.

```
return ReactElement(
    type,
    key,
    ref,
    self,
    source,
    ReactCurrentOwner.current,
    props,
  );
```

Here [`ReactElement`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/de7d1c90718ea8f4844a2219991f7115ef2bd2c5/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L148) is a factory method. It creates an object and returns that. But you never have to worry about it.

It is like worrying about `addEventListener`. How do you know it actually works? :D

**PS:** There are no real classes in JS. ES6 classes are just an abstraction and are actually created using functions only.